# Cómo subir una imagen vía axios post en laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, axios

Estoy enviando un formulario que debe hacerse vía axios (originalmente se enviaba como un formulario tradicional usando el método post). El problema es que no estoy logrando enviar la imagen a laravel, obtengo null o la validación falla con status 422.

El input de la imagen es el siguiente:

```
<form id="groups-form" method="POST" action="{{route('groups.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   
    <input id="thumbnail" type="file" name="thumbnail">
```

Y en la parte de axios lo siguiente:

```
let name = $("#name").val();
let groupsRequest = $("#groups").val();
let thumbnail = $("#thumbnail").val();
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    url: '{{route('groups.store')}}',
    data: {
        'name': name,
        'groups' : groupsRequest,
        'thumbnail' : thumbnail
    },
})
```

El controlador lo tengo así:

```
$imageUrl = $this->uploadImage($locationGroupRequest);
$groupId = $this->groupRepository->saveGroup($locationGroupRequest, $imageUrl);
return response()->json(['success', compact('groupId')]);
```

La función `uploadImage` es esta:

```
if ($locationGroupRequest->has('thumbnail')) {
    $validator = Validator::make($locationGroupRequest->all(), [
        'thumbnail' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
    $file = $locationGroupRequest->file('thumbnail');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filenameToStore = $locationGroupRequest->input('name') . '.' . $extension;

    return $this->compressImage($file, $filenameToStore);
} else {
    return '';
}
```

Cabe recalcar que todo en la parte del servidor en laravel ya estaba funcionando de manera correcta antes de intentar usar axios.

Comment: has logrado ver, como sale la solicitud desde axios..?? creo que tu problema puede venir de que, tienes que crear un `formData()` y enviarlo en lugar del `val()`

Comment: @Josbert al parecer creo que es eso, pero no tengo formData(), creo

Comment: Has la prueba, así: `let formData = new FormData();` luego agrégale el campo así, `formData.append('thumbnail', $("#thumbnail").val())` y el tu data de axios envías el objeto que acabas de crear, o sea `formData`. Prueba esto

Comment: Ojo, solo envía el objeto completo en la data de **axios**, ejemplo: `data: formData` junto con tus **headers** y el resto claro, puedes hacer que se agregue el valor del input al FormData con cada evento `onchange` ejemplo

Comment: @Josbert no me ha funcionado :/ edit: ya me funcionó, publicaré respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias a @Josbert lo he podido solucionar viendo que estaba obteniendo el valor de un input y no el archivo:
el problema era que obtenía a través de Jquery un "valor" del input y no así el archivo, esto se hace con

```
$('#thumbnail')[0].files[0];
```

básicamente todo se mantiene igual, pero a la hora de hacer el envío por **axios**, quedaría así:

```
            let formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('name', $("#name").val());
            formData.append('groups', $("#groups").val());
            formData.append('thumbnail', $('#thumbnail')[0].files[0]);
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '{{route('groups.store')}}',
                data: formData,
```

**NOTA:** en adición a lo mecionado anteriormente, en una charla con @Josbert al cual le agradezco mucho su tiempo; hay un problema con esto cuando el método cambia a put/path (cualquiera de ellos), al parecer se debe a las limitaciones de los métodos **http** estándar (**POST|GET**); ya que el contenido de la solicitud es de tipo `multipart/form-data` y Laravel solo interpreta de manera correcta estas anteriores. Se puede solucionar de la siguiente manera:

1. Cambiar en axios el método PUT a POST
2. añadir al formulario, un campo llamado '_method' con el valor

resultado para el método PUT o PATCH:

```
          let formData = new FormData();

          formData.append('name', $("#name").val());
          formData.append('groups', $("#groups").val());
          formData.append('thumbnail', $('#thumbnail')[0].files[0]);
          formData.append('_method', 'PATCH');
             axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '{{route('groups.update', $locationGroup->id)}}',
                data: formData,
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data' },
```

y con esto funciona de maravilla pasando las validaciones especiales (mi caso) en caso de que el método usado sea PUT o PATCH

Comment: Me da gustoo..!! habia olvidado el `$('#thumbnail')[0].files[0]` por suerte te diste cuenta, buenísimo. P.D: no es necesario que quites el **header** de hecho lo mas correcto es que lo dejes, pero veo que de igual forma funciona

Comment: @Josbert acabo de enterarme que la validación está fallando debido a que estoy enviando todo el formData ahora del lado de laravel, no encuentra el campo "name", cómo puedo acceder a él? ya que si envio thumbnail como lo hacía antes nuevamente no lo envía como archivo

Comment: La validación no debería falla, recuerda añadir el **header** `'Content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'` déjalo como lo tienes en el ejemplo, y lo validas en *Laravel* como `$request->validate([ 'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255' ]);`

Comment: Si la validación de tu `input type="file"` falla, puedes probar algo como esto `$request->validate([ 'thumbnail.*' => 'max:2048' ]);`

Comment: tengo una clase llamada LocationGroupRequest donde lo que valida es el campo name mediante esta línea         $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]; pero está fallando, en la consola veo el mensaje {name: ["The name field is required."]}, ya tengo el header de nuevo y sigue fallando ese campo, ojo que esto ocurre cuando quiero editar y no cuando creo uno nuevo, lo peor es que el código es prácticamente similar

Comment: Todo depende de como este saliendo esto desde **axios**, te aconsejo que veas eso, quizá con un `console.log(formData)`

Comment: haciendo un log a formData justo antes donde inicia axios luce vacío

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127256/discussion-between-josbert-and-andre-cuellar-avaroma).